# Convert Dictionary to Python Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
Dict = {'type': 'book', 'text_eng': 'National accounts', 'text': 'Volkswirtschaftliche Gesamtrechnungen', 'anchor': 'GESAMTVOLK'}
pd.DataFrame(Dict)
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dict)
```

Above script throws error: "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

I need Dictionary Keys as DataFrame Columns & Dictionary Values in rows.

Below script working fine as Dictionary Values added as List

```
Dict = {'type': ['book'], 'text_eng': ['National accounts'], 'text': ['Volkswirtschaftliche Gesamtrechnungen'], 'anchor': ['GESAMTVOLK']}
```

Please let me know how to achiev this?

Comment: Dont use reservered words as variable name, like `Dict`, `dict`, `list` etc.

Comment: If you only have one row of data, `pd.DataFrame(dct, index=[0])` will work. Note I changed `Dict` -> `dct`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: @Erfan, Noted... will follow.. .thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd

D = {'type': 'book', 'text_eng': 'National accounts', 'text': 'Volkswirtschaftliche Gesamtrechnungen', 'anchor': 'GESAMTVOLK'}
a = pd.DataFrame([D])
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
       anchor                                   text           text_eng  type
0  GESAMTVOLK  Volkswirtschaftliche Gesamtrechnungen  National accounts  book
```